# How can I fill missing elements in a Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

(Pandas beginner here)

With the following code:

```
a = pd.Series(range(0, 10))
b = a[a % 2 == 0]

print b
```

I get:

```
0    0
2    2
4    4
6    6
8    8
dtype: int64
```

How can I fill the missing indexes with a value? for example 10, so I would get:

```
0    0
1    10
2    2
3    10
4    4
5    10
6    6
7    10
8    8
9    10
```

Comment: `np.where(a % 2 == 0, a, 10)` or `a.where(a % 2 == 0, 10)` to keep a series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `reindex`

Considering you already have the index defined in `a`

```
b.reindex(a.index, fill_value=10)

0     0
1    10
2     2
3    10
4     4
5    10
6     6
7    10
8     8
9    10
dtype: int64
```

---

Or

```
b.reindex(range(10), fill_value=10)
```

Comment: this is the best fitting solution in my context.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code below:

```
b=a.apply(lambda x: 10 if x%2 != 0 else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing with `b = a[a % 2 == 0]` is getting a Series containing all (and only) values of a where `a % 2` is `0`. So the missing elements don't exist at all in `b`.

If I understand correctly, what you're trying to do is just replace all values that meet the condition with a different value. One way you could do that is:

```
b = a.apply(lambda x: x if x % 2 == 0 else 10)
```